# Alternatives to Matlab's Mat File Format

Tags: matlab

I'm finding that writing and reading the native mat file format becomes very, very slow with larger data structures of about 1G in size.  In addition we have other, non-matlab, software that should be able to read and write these files.  So I would to find an alternative format to use to serialize matlab data structures.  Ideally this format would ...

1. be able to represent an arbitrary matlab structure to a file.

   have faster I/O than than mat files.

   have I/O libraries for other languages like Java, Python and C++.

Comment: For your second point, I guess mat files are already optimized for I/O speed. For instance, they are compressed to minimize I/O. For your third point, you can save with the `-ascii` format to make it readable by any other program, but it is going to be slower.

Comment: When you say "arbitrary matlab structure", how complex are these things? That'll affect speed. Like Oli says, MAT files are compressed, but the compression is done internally on each mxarray, not the overall file, so it can actually slow I/O down for complex data structures.

Comment: @Andrew We have struct arrays which have arrays of doubles within.  We have structs with matrices of doubles, these structs also have cell arrays of varying size.   I should also mention there are roughly two kinds of use cases for these files.  One is to load them on an individual workstation for assessment of the algorithms and for scientific purposes.  The other use case is just to move around bulk data from a supercomputer back to where the data is eventually stored.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simplifying your data structures and using the new v7.3 MAT file format, which is a variant of HDF5, might actually be the best approach. The HDF5 format is open and already has I/O libraries for your other languages. And depending on your data structure, they may be faster than the old binary mat files.

- Simplify the data structures you're saving, preferring large arrays of primitives to complex container structures.
- Try turning off compression if your data structures are still complex.
- Try the v7.3 MAT file format using "-v7.3"
- If using a network file system, consider saving and loading to a temporary dir on a fast local drive and copying to/from the network

For large data structures, your MAT file I/O speed may be determined more by the internal structure of the data you're writing out than the size of the resulting MAT file itself. (In my experience, this has usually been the major factor in slow MAT files.) When you say "arbitrary Matlab structure", that suggests you might be using cells, structs, or objects to make complex data structures. That slows down MAT I/O because there is per-array overhead in MAT file I/O, and the members of cell and struct arrays (container types) all count as separate arrays. For example, 5,000 strings stored in a cellstr are much, much slower than the same 5,000 strings stored in a 2-D char array. And objects have even more overhead. As a test, try writing out a 1 GB file that contains just a 1 GB primitive array of random uint8s, and see how long that takes. From there, see if you can simplify your data to reduce the total mxarray count, even if that means reshaping it for serialization. (My experience with this is mostly with the v7 format; the newer HDF5 format may have less per element overhead.)

If your data files live on the network, you could also try doing the save and load operations on temporary files on fast local drives, and separately using copy operations to move them back and forth between the network. At least on Windows networks, I've seen speedups of up to 2x from doing this. Possibly due to optimizations the full-file copy operation can do that the MAT I/O code can't.

It would probably be a substantial effort to come up with an alternate file format that supported fully arbitrary Matlab data structures and was portable to other languages. I'd try making smaller changes around your use of the existing format first.

Comment: It's interesting you mention writing out files over a network file system.  Unfortunately many of the machines we run on are supercomputer nodes; these do not have any kind of local storage device.  Some work has been done to destructure the data and covert to single precision.  Indeed, this has been very helpful.  I'll see what happens with some of your other suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

mat format has changed with Matlab versions. v7.3 uses HDF5 format, which has builtin compression and other features and it can take a large time to read/write. However, you can force Matlab to use previous formats which are faster (but might take more space).

See here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/mat-file-versions.html

Comment: Note that v7.3 isn't the default format, even for newer versions of Matlab, and pre-v7.3 MAT files also use compression. Fiddling with the format version and compression independently might be necessary.

Comment: @Andrew Janke actually the link says version 6 doesn't use compression.

Comment: Right, but the version 7 format, which is the default and is distinct from the HDF5 based v7.3 format, does. Just saying that the v7.3 format isn't the only one using compression, and if OP checks his file format and sees that it's v7, he'll still need to consider compression.

Comment: -1. When the speed bottleneck is I/O speed more than computation speed (as it is these days), compression *helps* read HDF5 files faster. See http://www.pytables.org/docs/manual-2.2.1/ch05.html particularly the graph of read speed.

Comment: @JasonS actually this is only true for reading, since decompression is almost trivial computationally. The main computation in compression is when writing - look at the writing speed in the link you posted, there is a big difference.